# I was on the SE podcast talking about Ask Ubuntu, check it out!

Tags: discussion

last week the StackExchange guys asked me to get on the podcast to talk about Ubuntu!

- http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/06/podcast-48-sponsored-by-powdermilk-biscuits/?cb=1

Skip to 30:53 if you want to ignore all the other stuff and get right to the AU discussion.  I hope I represented the site well, enjoy!

Comment: Lol I actually enjoyed the first 30 minutes (Specially the first 15 seconds haha). Thanks Jorge.

Comment: Actually it's from 28:55 that they start talking about AskUbuntu

Comment: Nice, but in what way is this a question? I mean: do you want us to react to the podcast? If not I think it is bit bizarre that regularly these type of non-questions [like 'please don't close ...'] pop up in meta (often by high rep users). Or is that ok on meta?

Comment: Meta is what we want it to be, it kind of gets mangled into discussion sometimes, but that's ok.

Comment: They called you a moderator when they introduced you xD